# Google Analytics 4 (GA4) counter initialization without pageview

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have a problem with GA4.

I need the first time a user visits the site (when he does not have any cookies google) with the first pageview sent a cookie **_ga** which stores **ClientID** and another cookie with information about the session.

In previous version of **GA3** counter you could use parameter **gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY', { send_page_view: false })**
In that case, the counter would create a cookie, but would not send pageview. After creating the cookie, we sent **gtag('config', .... )** with the **ClientID** parameters we wanted.

But in GA4 when using **gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT_ID', { send_page_view: false })** the cookie is not set at all.

Does anyone know how to make the cookies are created but the pageview is not sent?

**Without GTM!**

Comment: why not just setting the cookie directly? If you're going to set the client id anyway, then why need gtag's help to make a cookie?

Comment: not only client id i needed. _ga_******* that cookie with sessionID for example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

#### Ad blockers

Check if nothing is blocking the sending to GA in your browser, like AD blockers or even Firefox:

[image]

#### Misconfiguration of data layer

Maybe your data layer is corrupted. Try to copy the exact snippet from GA.

#### Cookie Consent Tools

Maybe some Consent Tools are blocking cookies, try:

```js
gtag('consent', 'update', {
  ad_storage: 'granted',
  analytics_storage: 'granted',
});
```

#### Final

If all it's ok, GA will send `collect` requests:

[image]